# Community Builder Self Registration Custom Fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I am looking to build a better version of the included "selfRegister" component that is included with Community Builder.  In particular, I would like to allow for an admin to configure which fields to display to the user...

The included "selfRegister" component has a design property called "extraFieldsFieldSet" that allows for an administrator (i.e. non-developer) to configure which fields are displayed on the form.  The way in which it is implemented is kind of limiting.  Here is a code snipped for what it is doing:

```
<aura:iteration aura:id="extraFields" items="{!v.extraFields}" var="curField" indexVar="index">
    <div id="sfdc_extrafield_container" class="sfdc">
        <span id="sfdc_user" class="login-icon" data-icon="a"></span>
        <ui:inputText value="{!curField.value}" aura:id="{!curField.fieldPath}" placeholder="{!curField.label}" keyup="{!c.onKeyUp}" class="input sfdc_extrafieldinput sfdc"/>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

This code basically loops through all fields in the specified field set and outputs a label and textbox.  This is pretty limiting since there are many other fields types (such as a picklist) which call for different input types.  Also, there is not a concept of a "page section" like there is for page layouts.  In an ideal situation, an administrator would be able to design a page layout just for the self-registrations with many fields and sections.  Then, leverage the built-in facilities to populate an sObject and save it to the system.

One way that I can think of to do this is by creating my own "metadata" objects (perhaps using custom settings) and allow for the administrator to configure fields that way.  This seems less than ideal, but could work.